# Where To add reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Modeling.Diagrams?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, reference

I have gone to the "Reference" in Solution Explorer and tried to add it from "Framework" under "Assemblies" in the Reference Manager. Is there something that I'm missing in term of having a service pack installed? The MSDN page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.modeling.diagrams.hslcolor(v=vs.110).aspx)

In VS 2010 , I have Microsoft.VisualStudio.Modeling.Integration but not Modeling.Diagrms

please advise... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading this:

[Visual Studio modeling SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23025)

This should give you the assemblies you need.